# Facebook Integration Static access token

Tags: django, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'm trying to use the facebook API on the backend of a website. Essentially, I want to be able to create events using a Djano app and have it create the corresponding facebook events.

The organization I am creating events for already have a facebook page. I only am concerned with posting events on that organization's page. I am the admin for the organization so I know all the login info.

What I am am trying to figure out is how I can setup the access token such thatit just works for the organization without any need to login to the facebook app. I was thinking that setting a static access token would do the trick, but I cannot find anyway to do it.

So, what is the standard way to create a facebook app that only interfaces with one predefined user?

Answer (score 0):

Im not entirely sure what you're trying to do. However the static access token has now been deprecated. Do you want to: create an event for the person using the page, or for the company's page/profile?

Hope I can help

Comment: Hi specifically, I am trying to create events for an organization's facebookpage. I already have a Django based system that creates events on the organization's website. What I would like to do is make it so that when an even it created in this Django backend, a corresponding event is created on the organization's facebook page. The reason I ask about static tokens is that I don't want to have to worry about the token expiring and breaking this backend functionality.